# Some logs are missed in NSIS Installation log

Tags: logging, installation, nsis

I am using special build of NSIS that supports installation logs. It works fine but there are some cases that logs are partially saved for one section. It means some logs are missed. I am not sure what can be the reason for this issue. If NSIS archives log files if it exceeds size? What happens if some errors or exceptions (for example blocking some exe by anti virus) occur during installation?

Here is the structure of install script:

```
    !include "FileFunc.nsh"
    !include "WinMessages.nsh"
    !include "x64.nsh"
    !include "WinVer.nsh"
    !include "WordFunc.nsh"
    !include "LogicLib.nsh"

    RequestExecutionLevel admin
    ShowInstDetails nevershow
    ShowUninstDetails nevershow
    AutoCloseWindow true
    SetCompressor lzma

    ;major, minor, date, build
    !define VERSION "1.0.0.1"

    ;Project name and version
    !define PROJECT "Project1"
    !define CONFIG_NAME "Config1"
    !define SERVICE_NAME "Service01"
    !define PROCESS_EXE "Process01.exe"
    !define GUI_EXE "MainUI.exe"
    !define COMMONDRIVER_EXE "ComDriver_v1.0.0.0.exe"
    !define DEVICEDRIVER_EXE "DeviceDriver_v1.0.0.0.exe"
    !define UNINSTALL_EXE "Uninstall.exe"

    Name "${PROJECT}"
    OutFile "${PROJECT}_Setup_v${VERSION}.exe"

    !macro Cleanup
        RMDir /r "$APPDATA\Company\Product\Service\Folder01"
        
        RMDir /r "$INSTDIR\WPFUI"
        
        SetRegView 32
        DeleteRegKey HKLM "SOFTWARE\Company\Product\${PROJECT}"
    !macroend

    !macro WriteRegInfo 
        SetRegView 32 
        WriteRegStr HKLM "SOFTWARE\Company\Product\${PROJECT}" "ProductVersion" "${VERSION}"
        WriteRegStr HKLM "SOFTWARE\Company\Product\${PROJECT}" "InstallDir" "$INSTDIR"
        WriteRegStr HKLM "SOFTWARE\Company\Product\${PROJECT}" "UninstallPath" "$WINDIR\${UNINSTALL_UTILITY}"
        WriteRegStr HKLM "SOFTWARE\Company\Product\${PROJECT}" "UninstallerPath" "$APPDATA\Company\Product\Uninstall\${PROJECT}\${PROJECT}_${UNINSTALL_EXE}"
    !macroend

    ;install init
    Function .onInit
        !cd "..\..\NSIS\Build"
        SetShellVarContext all
        !insertmacro InitInstallDir
        
        ;UI has no staging folder.
        !insertmacro WaitForGUI
        !insertmacro StopServices
        
        ;copy prerequisites to temporary folder
        InitPluginsDir
        SetOutPath "$PLUGINSDIR"
        File "..\..\..\driverInstaller\RzCom\${COMMONDRIVER_EXE}"
        File "..\..\..\driverIinstaller\${DEVICEDRIVER_EXE}"

    FunctionEnd

    Section "install-commondriver"
        ExecWait '"$PLUGINSDIR\${COMMONDRIVER_EXE}" /S' $0
        ${If} $0 != 0
            SetErrorLevel $0
        ${EndIf}
    SectionEnd

    Section "install-devicedriver"
        ExecWait '"$PLUGINSDIR\${DEVICEDRIVER_EXE}" /S' $0
        ${If} $0 != 0
            SetErrorLevel $0
        ${EndIf}

        ExecWait '"$PLUGINSDIR\${MIDDLEWARE_EXE}" /S' $0
    SectionEnd

    Section "install"
        !insertmacro Cleanup
        
        SetOutPath "$APPDATA\Company\Product\Folder01"
        File /r ".\Devices\Defaults\${PID}"
        
        SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\WPFUI"
        File /r ".\UI\Company.UI"
            
        !cd "${__FILEDIR__}"
        ;send signed uinstaller
        SetOutPath "$APPDATA\Company\Product\Uninstall\${PROJECT}"
        File "${PROJECT}_${UNINSTALL_EXE}"
        
        !insertmacro WriteRegInfo
        ${If} $ISLASTMODULE != "FALSE"
            !insertmacro StartServices
        ${EndIf}
    SectionEnd
    ;--------------------------------

    !macro InitInstallDir
    ;prioritize registry
        SetRegView 32
        
        ${GetParameters} $0
        
        StrCpy $INSTDIR ""
        ${GetOptions} "$0" "/LWIDIR=" $INSTDIR
            
        ${If} $INSTDIR != ""
            StrCpy $INSTDIR "$INSTDIR\Product"
        ${Else} 
            ReadRegStr $INSTDIR HKLM "SOFTWARE\Company\Product\Product01" "InstallDir"
        ${EndIf}
        
        ${If} $INSTDIR == ""
            StrCpy $INSTDIR "$PROGRAMFILES32\Company\Product"
        ${EndIf}
        
        
        StrCpy $ISLASTMODULE "TRUE"
        ${GetOptions} "$0" "/ISLASTMODULE=" $ISLASTMODULE
        
        ${If} $ISLASTMODULE != ""
            ${StrFilter} "$ISLASTMODULE" "+" "" "" $ISLASTMODULE
        ${Else}
            StrCpy $ISLASTMODULE "TRUE"
        ${EndIf}
        
        !insertmacro EnableLogsWithHeader
    !macroend

    !macro EnableLogsWithHeader
      ; Get the date and time
      ${GetTime} "" "L" $0 $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6
      
      ; Turn on logging. This command must be after $INSTDIR
      LogSet On

      ; Log the date and time
      LogText "/******************* $0/$1/$2 ($3) $4:$5:$6 *******************/"
    !macroend

    !macro StopServices
        SimpleSC::ExistsService "${SERVICE_NAME}"
        Pop $0
        ${If} $0 == 0
            SimpleSC::StopService "${SERVICE_NAME}" 1 30        
            !insertmacro WaitForSynapseService
            !insertmacro WaitForProcess     
        ${EndIf}
    !macroend

    !macro WaitForService
        StrCpy $COUNTER "0"
        ${Do}
            ${nsProcess::FindProcess} "${SERVICE_EXE}" $R0
                ${If} $R0 == 0
                    Sleep 3000
                    IntOp $COUNTER $COUNTER + 1
                ${Else}
                    ${Break}
                ${EndIf}
                
                ${If} $COUNTER >= 10
                    ${nsProcess::KillProcess} "${SERVICE_EXE}" $R0
                ${EndIf}
        ${Loop}
    !macroend

    !macro WaitForProcess
    StrCpy $COUNTER "0"
        ${Do}
            ${nsProcess::FindProcess} "${PROCESS_EXE}" $R0
                ${If} $R0 == 0
                    ${nsProcess::KillProcess} "${PROCESS_EXE}" $R0
                    Sleep 1000
                    IntOp $COUNTER $COUNTER + 1
                ${Else}
                    ${Break}
                ${EndIf}
                
                ${If} $COUNTER >= 3
                    ${Break}
                ${EndIf}
        ${Loop}
    !macroend

    !macro WaitForGUI
    StrCpy $COUNTER "0"
        ${Do}
            ${nsProcess::FindProcess} "${GUI_EXE}" $R0
                ${If} $R0 == 0
                    ${nsProcess::KillProcess} "${GUI_EXE}" $R0
                    Sleep 1000
                    IntOp $COUNTER $COUNTER + 1
                ${Else}
                    ${Break}
                ${EndIf}
                
                ${If} $COUNTER >= 3
                    ${Break}
                ${EndIf}
        ${Loop}
    !macroend

    !macro StopServices
        SimpleSC::ExistsService "${SERVICE_NAME}"
        Pop $0
        ${If} $0 == 0
            SimpleSC::StopService "${SERVICE_NAME}" 1 30        
            !insertmacro WaitForService
            !insertmacro WaitForProcess     
        ${EndIf}    
    !macroend
```

This is sample install.log that is truncated, My logs starts with a date / time header that is missed.

```
    CreateDirectory: "C:\ProgramData\Company\Product\Uninstall\Product01" (1)
    CreateDirectory: "C:\ProgramData\Company\Product\Uninstall\Product01" created
    File: overwriteflag=0, allowskipfilesflag=2, name="Product01_Uninstall.exe"
    File: wrote 50072 to "C:\ProgramData\Company\Product\Uninstall\Product01\Product01_Uninstall.exe"
    SetFlag: 12=0
    WriteRegStr: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Company\Product\Product01" "ProductVersion"="3.5.1215.120103"
    WriteRegStr: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Company\Product\Product01" "InstallDir"="C:\Program Files (x86)\Company\Product"
    WriteRegStr: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Company\Product\Product01" "UninstallPath"="C:\Windows\Installer\Uninstaller.exe"
    WriteRegStr: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Company\Product\Product01" "UninstallerPath"="C:\ProgramData\Company\Product\Uninstall\Product01\Product01_Uninstall.exe"
    Delete: DeleteFile("C:\Windows\TEMP\nswCEA7.tmp\nsProcess.dll")
    Delete: DeleteFile on Reboot("C:\Windows\TEMP\nswCEA7.tmp\nsProcess.dll")
    Delete: DeleteFile("C:\Windows\TEMP\nswCEA7.tmp\PID0085Drv_v0.1.0.0.exe")
    Delete: DeleteFile("C:\Windows\TEMP\nswCEA7.tmp\ComDriver_v1.0.0.0.exe")
    Delete: DeleteFile("C:\Windows\TEMP\nswCEA7.tmp\SimpleSC.dll")
    Delete: DeleteFile("C:\Windows\TEMP\nswCEA7.tmp\System.dll")
    RMDir: RemoveDirectory("C:\Windows\TEMP\nswCEA7.tmp\")
    RMDir: RemoveDirectory on Reboot("C:\Windows\TEMP\nswCEA7.tmp\")
```

Comment: I don't think there is a log size limit and if there is, it is at least 2 GB.

Comment: That is what I also believe is not the root cause for this problem. But there were some feedback maybe NSIS internally has some size limit. I have not checked their source code. It is very strange why  logs are shown from middle of a section.

Comment: Post a minimal example with the issue I might be able to take a look.

Comment: I have updated by an example.

Comment: The example you posted does not compile. Also, please produce a example without 3rd-party plug-ins. When I move things around to make it compile and comment out some stuff I cannot reproduce your issue...